# Change a value in the driver INF file

Tags: windows-7, drivers, inf

**Driver**: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter

**OS**: Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 - x64

**Purpose**: Changing the Channel of wifi

For knowing which files are being used by the above mentioned driver, I used a tool called [DriverExtractor](http://www.grandutils.com/DriverExtractor/). The result are these files:

```
athrextx.cat
athrx.sys
netathrx.inf
```

`defaultIbssChannel` is the value in the `netathrx.inf` that I'm interested in:

```
[adhocchannelselect.reg]
HKR, Ndi\params\defaultIbssChannel,     ParamDesc,                      0,        %adhocchannel%
HKR, Ndi\params\defaultIbssChannel,     default,                        0,        "10"
HKR, Ndi\params\defaultIbssChannel,     min,                            0,        "1"
HKR, Ndi\params\defaultIbssChannel,     max,                            0,        "11"
HKR, Ndi\params\defaultIbssChannel,     step,                           0,        "1"
HKR, Ndi\params\defaultIbssChannel,     base,                           0,        "10"
HKR, Ndi\params\defaultIbssChannel,     type,                           0,        "int"
.
.
.
HKR, ,                                  defaultIbssChannel,             0x00002,  "11"
```

There's no key or value in the registry as `defaultIbssChannel`
So I searched my whole Windows drive and find `netathrx.inf` in these places:

```
C:\Windows\inf
C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\netathrx.inf_amd64_neutral_11fc8a486f2a66fd
C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\netathrx.inf_amd64_neutral_594f4aa1786993fb
C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\netathrx.inf_amd64_neutral_e4fa711280ff8fd4
C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\netathrx.inf_amd64_neutral_fd83bf6c5bba7e25
C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_netathrx.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_cf0144fd71b44a1a
```

Finally my question is that: Which of the `netathrx.inf` files in above locations should be edited so that the new value takes effect?

**Update 1:**
The `netathrx.inf` files in the `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\...`are the most recent one, but other locations hold the older version of the file.

Comment: You can change the channel of the wifi in your Router much easier, which will force your wifi adapter to use that channel. Doing what you want to do will not change the channel as the router controls that.

Comment: It's an internal component in my laptop. There's no exterior router

Comment: It has to connect to a router, otherwise you would have to internet connection.

Comment: You might edit your question and clarify what you are trying to accomplish in the end,

Comment: it's not that much complicated, My phone needs to be connected to the internet. It uses android and so can't connect to an ad-hoc network; so I have created a wifi-hotspot with connectify and route my internet connectivity(LAN) in to it. I want to change the channel that wifi is using; right now it's 11

Comment: Add that information to your question please.

Comment: Seem that he's trying to add an ad hoc Software AP using his WiFi adapter...

Answer (score 0):

Opening an administrator command shell and typing `netsh wlan show drivers` will give you the currently used driver for that interface.

```
Interface name: WiFi 2

    Driver                    : TP-LINK Wireless USB Adapter
    Vendor                    : TP-LINK
    ...
    INF file                  : C:\Windows\INF\oem20.inf
    Files                     : 1 total
                                C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\athuwbx.sys
    Type                      : Native Wi-Fi Driver
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect to a wireless router on a different channel. The channel on which you'll broadcast your ad hoc network will also change.